# enforce single connections to straight lines

Tags: graphviz, dot

I have a dot graph with many nodes and connections and it works fine.
But i want to add a few single connections that should be drawn as straight lines without any layout processing.

Here is an example node. The line should be drawn right through the middle cell, but dot renders a loop that cuts through the all the cells, instead just through the center one.

```
digraph TEST
{
  rankdir=LR;
  node [shape=plaintext];   


  datamodify1 [label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" >
  <TR>
    <TD COLSPAN="3" BGCOLOR="azure3" HREF="\ref DataModify" TOOLTIP="datamodify1"><FONT FACE="Times-Roman" POINT-SIZE="12.0" >  datamodify1  </FONT></TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD PORT="intestData" BGCOLOR="0.6 0.5 0.5"><FONT FACE="Times-Roman" POINT-SIZE="8.0" >  testData  </FONT></TD>
    <TD ROWSPAN="2" BGCOLOR="azure3"><FONT FACE="Times-Roman" POINT-SIZE="12.0" >  process  </FONT></TD>
    <TD PORT="outtestData"  BGCOLOR="0.6 0.5 0.5"><FONT FACE="Times-Roman" POINT-SIZE="8.0" >  testData  </FONT></TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD PORT="intestData2" BGCOLOR="green"><FONT FACE="Times-Roman" POINT-SIZE="8.0" >  testData3  </FONT></TD>
    <TD><FONT FACE="Times-Roman" POINT-SIZE="8.0" > </FONT></TD>
  </TR>


</TABLE>>];
datamodify1:intestData:e -> datamodify1:outtestData:w;

}
```

[image: dot generates this]

Bonuspoints:
The most ideal outcome would be, if the resulting line does not cuts the text 
in the middle box (maybe slightly curves around it) even if there is no second row or the line has to be drawn from the bottom left to the top right box.